# How could I write a script in python to return a list of boolean values

Tags: python, list, algorithm, loops

Id like to write a script in python that can return a list of boolean value, that changes the value based on whether or not it hits a keyword.

Example: if I have a list

```
["hello", "what", "switch", "am", "i", "doing", "switch", "here"]
```

I need to get it to return:

```
[True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True]
```

essentially it'll change the boolean value (always beginning as true) for itself and the following elements until it hits the keyword (switch in this case).

So far I've gotten it to only change the switch keyword itself to false.

My code looks like this:
(I know where I am going wrong and why its only changing one element, this is just where I got stuck on the problem)

```
def flick_switch(lst):
    x = []
    for i in lst:
        if i == "switch":
            x.append(False)
        else:
            x.append(True)
```

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/4727702) for formatting information.

Comment: your code is fine, add `return x` at the end, same indentation level as the `for`. By default every function returns `None`

Comment: @cards missing return statement aside, the code isn't fine.

Comment: @jarmod you are right! I misread the part with the _switch logics_

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a variable that will track the current state and switch it when you encounter the "switch" word:

```
def flick_switch(lst):
    x = []
    current_state = True
    for i in lst:
        if i == "switch":
            current_state = not current_state
        x.append(current_state)
    return x
```

Note that `current_state = not current_state`, if `current_state` was `True` it will switch it to `False`, if `current_state` was `False` it'll switch it to `True`.

Comment: thank you so much! I didn't know not can be used as an on and off toggle. I really appreciate the answer

Comment: I think this is missing a return statement

Comment: You can write it as one liner using assignment operator - `x = [current_state := not current_state if i == "switch" else current_state for i in lst]`

Comment: I strongly encourage everyone ***not*** to abuse the `:=` operator in the way suggested in the above comment ;-)

Comment: @Stef In what sense is that "abuse"?

Comment: @CtrlZ The fact that this list comprehension works relies mainly on the fact that python variables are dynamic rather than scoped; relying on this behaviour inside a functional-style expression such as a list comprehension just makes the code much harder to read, understand and maintain, with no benefit.

Comment: @qwerty You can toggle between True and False using `a = not a`; you can toggle between 0 and 1 using `a = 1 - a`; you can toggle between +A and -A using `a = - a`; you can toggle between A and 1/A using `a = 1 / a`; you can toggle between two complex conjugates using `a = a.conjugate()`; you can toggle between any two values A and B using `a = B if a == A else A`; generally speaking, any [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) can be used as a toggle.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is only suited for people who really can't refrain from using itertools for everything; for normal people, I recommend following the advice from Yevhen's answer instead.

```py
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import eq

def flick_switch(lst):
    return list(accumulate(((s != 'switch') for s in lst), eq))

print(flick_switch(['hello', 'what', 'switch', 'am', 'i', 'doing', 'switch', 'here']))
# [True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True]
```

- [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Comment: Eventually you could use `operator.ne(s, 'switch')` or even turn it fully functional with `partial`... just matter of taste:)

Comment: @cards I think `reduce` does the same thing as `accumulate` except it only returns the last accumulated value instead of returning the full array? But the OP wants the full array.

Comment: @cards But maybe I could do `return list(accumulate(map(ne, lst, repeat('switch')), eq))`

Comment: Oh, yes, `return list(accumulate(map(partial(ne, 'switch'), lst), eq))`

Comment: @KellyBundy I knew this answer would attract you!!

Comment: Which one is "this"?

Comment: Do you have a counter-example ? `>>> flick_switch(['switch']*4)
[False, True, False, True]`

Comment: Sorry, false alarm, not sure what happened. Anyway, using `is_` might be better than `eq`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Can you believe that I spent several minutes looking for `xnor` in the operator module before I realised I could use `eq`?

Comment: Does that mean you started with `s == 'switch'` and `xor` like a normal person? :-) And then negated because they want to start true?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, in the history of edits you can still find the horrible first version which uses xor and adds an initial `True` using accumulate's optional parameter `initial`, and then removes the excess initial element using `next` :(

Comment: @KellyBundy Actually, no, if I remember correctly, I didn't negate everything when I was using xor, and then I wanted to switch to xnor by negating everything, and I noticed that I didn't need to negate everything to use xnor, which surprised me.